# Read speed from a mounted directory

Tags: linux, mount, directory, read

An application is loaded by mounting its content from a distant machine to a local dir. On some machines there is slow performance and I'd like to check the read speed of the files in the mounted dir.

`hdparm -Tt /dev/<dev_name>` works for drives and it is exactly what I require from the output but I cannot seem to run it for the mounted directory specifically.

Can you suggest me anything which could help to test the read speed for the files in that mounted dir?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.iozone.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bonnie++` is a commonly suggested tool for checking disk performance in a directory:

`bonnie++ -d $DIREC`

For quick order of magnitude answers I might be inclined to use pv (pipe view)

`cat file | pv > disk`